# A directed inverse limit of finite connected spaces is connected

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, connectedness, limits-colimits

Apparently, a directed inverse limit of finite connected spaces is connected. Does anyone have a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X=\lim_i X_i$ is a directed limit of finite connected spaces.

*Proof* — As $X_i$ are finite connected spaces, by the Mittag-Leffler condition we can replace the directed system of $X_i$ by one in which all the transition maps are surjective. (Each $X_i$, being the image of a connected space, is still connected.) As a directed limit of nonempty finite sets is nonempty, the projections $p_i : X \to X_i$ are then surjective. If $U$ and $V$ are complementary nonempty clopens in $X$, they are quasi-compact since $X$ is. Therefore since the system is directed there is an $i$ so that $U = p_i^{-1}(A)$ and $V = p_i^{-1}(B)$ for opens $A,B$ in $X_i$. The opens $A$ and $B$ are disjoint since $p_i$ is surjective and $U$ and $V$ are disjoint. Also $A$ and $B$ partition $X_i$ for the same reason. QED

Comment: Note that quasicompactness of the inverse limit is not trivial--in general, an inverse limit of quasicompact spaces need not be quasicompact.  In the finite case it is true because you can consider the inverse system where each space has the discrete topology instead, and then the inverse limit is compact since it is closed in the product topology.  The inverse limit topology for the original system is then coarser than this compact topology and thus is quasicompact.

Comment: Yup, that’s just the argument I had in mind.

Comment: What’s a cofiltered system ? Why does the Mittag-Leffler condition hold?

Comment: Cofiltered and directed are basically the same so I replaced the former with the latter. The ML condition holds because it holds in any inverse system of finite sets.

Comment: @EricWofsey Why wouldn't the inverse limit topology be the same as the compact topology induced by the injection into the product of the finite sets? This inverse limit topology isn't the topology induced by all the projections? Also if we have compact Hausdorff spaces the argument works.

Comment: @Idéophage: The problem is that the inverse limit is not closed in the product.  (For Hausdorff spaces it is, but not in general.)

Comment: @EricWofsey Ah ok I forgot what we were talking about. The finite sets are equipped with a topology coarser than the discrete one.